# how to optimized three for loop in python list

Tags: python

How do I optimize this code please suggest to me any other way, I tried but did not get any method to do this please suggest me?

python

```
arr = [1000,2000,6000,7000,3000,4000,5000,8000]
def fun(num):
  max_num = 0
  for i in range(len(num)):
      for j in range(i+1, len(num)):
        for x in range(j+1, len(num)):
          if num[i]+num[j]+num[x] > max_num:
              max_num = num[i]+num[j]+num[x]
              pairs = num[i],num[j], num[x]
  print(pairs)            
  print(max_num)
    
fun(arr)
```

Comment: what's the goal?

Comment: Look at [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: reduce time complexity

Comment: You can sort a list using sorted and sum up the largest 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely trying to get the largest 3 element sum. Try checking out the [two pointers algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/) for 2 element sums, and extend it to work with 3 elements. This will bring your algorithm from O(n^3) to O(n^2).